# Bevel Curve Mesh modelling

Tags: mesh

I'm trying to model the image of this control knob which has a curve to it.
I start off with a cylinder as shown in the example I've attached. select 4 vertices and make a face in the middle of the knob. But I also make another 2 faces left and right so I can make the bevel. When I select the edges and do make the bevel, as seen I'm getting some odd mesh result appearing. Is this the correct approach to model the reference image?

Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Add a Subdivision Modifier. You will likely need to create a small extrusion to the top to keep it flat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it this way, you need to extrude, mirror, bevel, cut, join...

[image]

Comment: Hi Moonboots,

Thanks for your example, that control knob looks awesomely modelled. I'm just a confused how did you make the join faces, I cannot figure it out, so I can continue on. if it's not much of a hassle for you, and do find free time, could you please do a quick demo tutorial how you made this.

Kind regards.

Comment: what join faces are you talking about? After the bevel you just need to join some vertices (J) and delete some edges (X > Dissolve Edges)

Comment: I thought I had uploaded the image.... Here is what's confusing me. The second step: https://ibb.co/NLKxbZ3

How did you get the quarter Cylinder?

Comment: I made some progress, I figured out the mirroring, and would like to know how you got the shape which is within the red rectangle. 

https://ibb.co/tBHmX6v

Comment: you need to select the edge on the corner and bevel with ctrl B ;) then you'll make some manual corrections: https://zupimages.net/up/19/43/bmd1.jpg

Comment: Hi Moonboots.

I'm getting closer to the result. On the left is what I've practised figuring out the mesh. But I noticed your models mesh cuts appear different just before the bevel.
What did you do to get that loop cut. I cannot make that loop cut, Im only getting half of the loop available to me. And also  you have made rectangles on your mesh which look cleaner.

https://ibb.co/pJymZCh

Kind regards.

Comment: Once bevelled I've used the knife tool: K to activate, C to cut orthogonally, Z to cut through   ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try dissolving the coplanar faces (the vertical side and the face on top of it). Worst case scenario you could do it with a boolean operation on a basic cylinder and the knob profile.